# Canvas/Bitmap scrolling question

Tags: delphi, canvas, bitmap, 2d, terrain

I'm trying to make a small game based on the canvas in Delphi. Basically, I'd like to make a fairly large bitmap ( 3000x3000, for example ), then load it into the canvas, and being able to scroll right/left/up/down just like an ordinary image viewer, however I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the image to an off-screen `TBitmap` object. Then, `OnPaint`, or whenever is suitable in your particular application, use `BitBlt` or `Canvas.Draw` to draw a rectangular subimage of the `TBitmap` onto the canvas. The subpart should start at `(X, Y)` on the `TBitmap` and have a width and height equal to `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` of the form, respectively.

Now, respond to keyboard events. Write a `FormKeyDown` event handler, and listen to `Key = VK_LEFT`, `Key = VK_RIGHT`, `Key = VK_UP`, and `Key = VK_DOWN` (use a `case` statement). When you detect such a key being pressed, increase/decrease `X` or `Y`, as appropriate, and paint the scene again using this starting point.

You can also respond to the `MouseDown`, `MouseMove`, and `MouseUp` events to scroll using the mouse. Either you can use the middle one only (`MouseMove`): You can check if the cursor is near an edge of the form, and if so, scroll in this direction smoothly (using a `TTimer`, for instance). Alternatively, you can set a `FMouseDown` flag to `true` in `MouseDown`, and reset it to `false` in `MouseUp`. Then, in `MouseMove`, scroll the bitmap by a delta `X-XOld` in the x direction if `FMouseDown` is `true`, and a delta `Y-YOld` in the y direction. (Here, `X` and `Y` are parameters of the `MouseMove` event handler; `(X, Y)` is the current position of the cursor.) The `MouseMove` procedure should end with

```
XOld := X;
YOld := Y;
```

no matter if `FMouseDown` is on or off.

Comment: To simplify things, you can use a TPaintBox inside a TScrollBox.  Set the TPaintBox dimensions to the size of the bitmap, use the OnPaint event to draw the bitmap, and use the OnMouse events to scroll the TScrollBox programmably.

Comment: Well, not as powerful, but might suffice for very simple needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My Bitmap is about 5000x5000 pixel, loaded into an Timage of 500x500 pixels.

I wrote a code to move the bitmap arround in the Timage, and it cant go out of the "borders"

AlteMausPos is declared in Form1 var at the beginning.
Kerzenbitmap is your bitmap that contains the 5000x5000 picture.
MausPosDifferenz contains the absolut amount of pixels(x,y) you have moved your mouse while mousekey down.

Then it checks if everything is in Range of the bitmap before copying it with CopyRect.

It took some time for my brain to find out that the best way to copy the rect ist to use the absolut changed mouseposition.

```
procedure Form1.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var picLimits: Tpoint;
begin
  AlteMausPos.X := X;
  AlteMausPos.Y := Y;
end;


procedure TForm1.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var SourceRect, DestRect: TRect;
begin
  var tempBMP:= Tbitmap.Create;
  MausPosDifferenz.X := MausPosDifferenz.X+ (AlteMausPos.X- X);
  MausPosDifferenz.Y := MausPosDifferenz.Y+ (AlteMausPos.Y- Y);
  if MausPosDifferenz.X >= Kerzenbitmap.Width- Image1.Width then MausPosDifferenz.X := Kerzenbitmap.Width-Image1.Width;
  if MausPosDifferenz.X < 0 then MausPosDifferenz.X:=0;
  if MausPosDifferenz.Y >= Kerzenbitmap.Height-Image1.Height then MausPosDifferenz.Y := Kerzenbitmap.Height-Image1.Height;
  if MausPosDifferenz.Y < 0 then MausPosDifferenz.Y:=0;

  SourceRect:=  Rect( MausPosDifferenz.X, MausPosDifferenz.Y, Image1.Width+ MausPosDifferenz.X, Image1.Height+ MausPosDifferenz.Y);
  DestRect:=    Rect( 0,0, Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
  tempBMP.Assign(Kerzenbitmap);
  TempBMP.Canvas.CopyRect(DestRect, Kerzenbitmap.Canvas, SourceRect);

  Image1.Picture.Assign(tempBMP);
  tempBMP.Free;
end;
```